# C++ String DD:HH:MM:SS to integer data types

Tags: c++, string, int, dynamic-cast

My question is simple. Given a string that represents time as DD:HH:MM:SS, with colons, how can I strip this into 4 separate data types of int?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to parse the text like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string time = "01:23:45:67";

    int secs;
    int mins;   
    int hours;    
    int days;
    char extra;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << time;
    ss >> days  >> extra
       >> hours >> extra
       >> mins  >> extra
       >> secs;

    std::cout << days << ":" << hours << ":" << mins << ":" << secs;
}
```